# Azure DevOps Update Refs - Delete Branch via API

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

implemented a function to delete a branch on the azure devops:

```
function Remove-RemoteBranch {
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]
    $CollectionUri,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]
    $TeamProject,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]
    $Repository,   
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]
    $BranchName, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]
    $BranchID,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$AccessToken
)
#create PAT in B64 format"
$B64_PAT = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AccessToken)"))

#Header for Authorization
$header = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + $B64_PAT }

$body = ConvertTo-Json (
    @{
        name        = $BranchName;
        oldObjectId = $BranchID;
        newObjectId = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
    })

$response = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post `
        -Uri "$($CollectionUri)/$($TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$($Repository)/refs/?api-version=4.1" `
        -Body $body `
        -ContentType "application/json" `
        -Headers $header `
        -UseBasicParsing)

if ($response.StatusCode -notmatch "200") {
    throw "Statuscode from RestRequest is $($Response.status)" 
}
```

}

I couldnt find a solution to my issue yet. I get the error "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: refUpdates" if I send a request to the server. I couldn't find any advices in the MS docu. May be some of you folks have an idea.

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

I have found the answer. The body has to look like this:

```
$body = ConvertTo-Json (
    @(
       @{
          name        = $BranchName;
          oldObjectId = $BranchID;
          newObjectId = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        }
     )
)
```

Comment: In PowerShell 7.4 I had to add the -AsArray parameter to get the correct generated json body. Otherwise if there is a single element it strips away the array notation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found my $body didn't have square brackets around it as per the docs

```
[
  {
    name        = $BranchName;
    oldObjectId = $BranchID;
    newObjectId = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
  }
]
```